# How to Access the Referring URL in a Streamlit Application?

Tags: python, web-applications, streamlit

In a Dash application, I've been using request.referrer from the Flask library to obtain the referring URL of the request, i.e., the URL of the page from which the user navigated. I'm looking to achieve the same functionality within a Streamlit application.

Is there a method, library, or a workaround in Streamlit that offers a similar capability to access the referring URL? Any guidance or examples on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to add a query parameter to the link to the Streamlit app (e.g. "myapp.streamlit.app?referrer=www.reddit.com"), you could then retrieve that value via [`st.experimental_get_query_params`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/utilities/st.experimental_get_query_params)

```
import streamlit as st

st.experimental_get_query_params()
```